# J2ME LWUIT TabbedPane: How to change the tabbedPane Backgroung color and font color?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am new to lwuit. I have to change the tab background color and font color. I used

```
Tabbedpannel tabpannel = new Tabbedpannel();
style tabcolor =tabpannel.setBgcolor(111);
```

but the color of the tab is not changing...

Any one can help me..?

Thanks in advance...

Nimmy..

Answer (score 0):

try `tabpannel.getStyle().setBgColor(111)`

Comment: TabbedPan id deprecated , use `Tabs` class, and use `Tabs tab = new Tabs(); tabs.getTabsContainer().getStyle().setBgColor(111);` for font color- use `setFgcolor()` method. use int 16711680 for test its red